Room with KMM: Unresolved reference 'instantiateImpl'
I'm trying to implement Room into my Kotlin Multiplatform project, and Im using the official docs at https://developer.android.com/kotlin/multiplatform/room
However, when trying to provide the RoomDatabaseBuilder, I cannot execute a function that the framework is supposed to generate
Project is created with the compose Multiplatform Wizard
root/composeApp/src/iosMain/kotlin/data/local/RoomDatabase.kt
fun buildDatabase(): RoomDatabase.Builder<KwontDb> {
    val dbFilePath = NSHomeDirectory() + "/my_room.db"
    return Room.databaseBuilder<KwontDb>(
        name = dbFilePath,
        factory = {
            KwontDb::class.instantiateImpl() 
          // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          // Unresolved reference 'instantiateImpl'.

        }
    )
}

composeApp/build.gradle.kts
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.ExperimentalKotlinGradlePluginApi
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.JvmTarget

plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsCompose)
    alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler)
    alias(libs.plugins.ksp)
    alias(libs.plugins.room)
}

kotlin {
    task("testClasses")
    androidTarget {
        @OptIn(ExperimentalKotlinGradlePluginApi::class)
        compilerOptions {
            jvmTarget.set(JvmTarget.JVM_11)
        }
    }
    
    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach { iosTarget ->
        iosTarget.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "ComposeApp"
            isStatic = true
        }
    }
    
    sourceSets {
        
        androidMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.preview)
            implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
        }
        commonMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.runtime)
            implementation(compose.foundation)
            implementation(compose.material)
            implementation(compose.ui)
            implementation(compose.components.resources)
            implementation(compose.components.uiToolingPreview)
            implementation(libs.kotlinx.coroutines.core)
            implementation(libs.multiplatform.settings)

            // Room
            implementation(libs.androidx.room.runtime)
        }
    }


}

android {
    namespace = "dk.mikkelthygesen.kwontgame"
    compileSdk = libs.versions.android.compileSdk.get().toInt()

    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    sourceSets["main"].res.srcDirs("src/androidMain/res")
    sourceSets["main"].resources.srcDirs("src/commonMain/resources")

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "dk.mikkelthygesen.kwontgame"
        minSdk = libs.versions.android.minSdk.get().toInt()
        targetSdk = libs.versions.android.targetSdk.get().toInt()
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    dependencies {
        debugImplementation(compose.uiTooling)
    }
}



room {
    schemaDirectory("$projectDir/schemas")
}

project build.gradle.kt
plugins {
    // this is necessary to avoid the plugins to be loaded multiple times
    // in each subproject's classloader
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.androidLibrary) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsCompose) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform) apply false
}

libs.versions.toml
[versions]
agp = "8.2.2"
android-compileSdk = "34"
android-minSdk = "24"
android-targetSdk = "34"
androidx-activityCompose = "1.9.0"
androidx-appcompat = "1.7.0"
androidx-constraintlayout = "2.1.4"
androidx-core-ktx = "1.13.1"
androidx-espresso-core = "3.5.1"
androidx-material = "1.12.0"
androidx-test-junit = "1.1.5"
compose-plugin = "1.6.10"
junit = "4.13.2"
kotlin = "2.0.0"
kotlinxCoroutinesCore = "1.9.0-RC"
multiplatformSettings = "1.1.1"
androidx-room = "2.7.0-alpha04"
ksp = "1.9.23-1.0.19"

[libraries]
androidx-room-compiler = { module = "androidx.room:room-compiler", version.ref = "androidx-room" }
androidx-room-gradle-plugin = { module = "androidx.room:room-gradle-plugin", version.ref = "androidx-room" }
androidx-room-runtime = { module = "androidx.room:room-runtime", version.ref = "androidx-room" }
kotlin-test = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test", version.ref = "kotlin" }
kotlin-test-junit = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit", version.ref = "kotlin" }
junit = { group = "junit", name = "junit", version.ref = "junit" }
androidx-core-ktx = { group = "androidx.core", name = "core-ktx", version.ref = "androidx-core-ktx" }
androidx-test-junit = { group = "androidx.test.ext", name = "junit", version.ref = "androidx-test-junit" }
androidx-espresso-core = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-core", version.ref = "androidx-espresso-core" }
androidx-appcompat = { group = "androidx.appcompat", name = "appcompat", version.ref = "androidx-appcompat" }
androidx-material = { group = "com.google.android.material", name = "material", version.ref = "androidx-material" }
androidx-constraintlayout = { group = "androidx.constraintlayout", name = "constraintlayout", version.ref = "androidx-constraintlayout" }
androidx-activity-compose = { module = "androidx.activity:activity-compose", version.ref = "androidx-activityCompose" }
kotlinx-coroutines-core = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core", version.ref = "kotlinxCoroutinesCore" }
multiplatform-settings = { module = "com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings", version.ref = "multiplatformSettings" }

[plugins]
androidApplication = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
androidLibrary = { id = "com.android.library", version.ref = "agp" }
jetbrainsCompose = { id = "org.jetbrains.compose", version.ref = "compose-plugin" }
compose-compiler = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.compose", version.ref = "kotlin" }
kotlinMultiplatform = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform", version.ref = "kotlin" }
ksp = { id = "com.google.devtools.ksp", version.ref = "ksp" }
room = { id = "androidx.room", version.ref = "androidx-room" 



This is a known issue that has also been reported by the following issuetracker.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/342905180

This is a workaround, but you can build it with the following code.

https://github.com/cvivek07/KMM-PicSplash/blob/main/composeApp/build.gradle.kts
https://github.com/cvivek07/KMM-PicSplash/blob/main/composeApp/src/commonMain/kotlin/database/AppDatabase.kt


Here is the solution with room = "2.7.0-alpha06"
// libs.versions.toml

[versions]
kotlin = "2.0.10"
roomVersion = "2.7.0-alpha06"
sqlite = "2.5.0-alpha06"
ksp = "2.0.0-1.0.21"

[libraries]
androidx-room-compiler = { module = "androidx.room:room-compiler", version.ref = "roomVersion" }
androidx-room-runtime = { module = "androidx.room:room-runtime", version.ref = "roomVersion" }
sqlite-bundled = { module = "androidx.sqlite:sqlite-bundled", version.ref = "sqlite" }

[plugins]
room = { id = "androidx.room", version.ref = "roomVersion" }
ksp = { id = "com.google.devtools.ksp", version.ref = "ksp" }

// composeApp/build.gradle.kts

plugins {
    ...
    // room
    alias(libs.plugins.ksp)
    // https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/343408758#comment4
//    alias(libs.plugins.room)
}

dependencies {
    ...
    // room
    add("kspAndroid", libs.androidx.room.compiler)
    add("kspIosSimulatorArm64", libs.androidx.room.compiler)
    add("kspIosX64", libs.androidx.room.compiler)
    add("kspIosArm64", libs.androidx.room.compiler)
}

// https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/343408758#comment4
//room {
//    schemaDirectory("$projectDir/schemas")
//}
ksp {
    arg("room.schemaLocation", "${projectDir}/schemas")
}

Create the following classes according to the official documentation.
https://developer.android.com/kotlin/multiplatform/room#defining-database

shared/src/commonMain/kotlin/Database.kt
shared/src/androidMain/kotlin/Database.kt
shared/src/iosMain/kotlin/Database.kt

Build

Android Studio > Build > Clean Project
Android Studio > Build > Rebuild Project

See

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/342905180#comment21


Have you compiled your project? Build -> Make project should generate the function.

Yes, the build compiler is also throwing the error
